# Inject Spring bean within RESTEasy Resource at Test time

Tags: rest, junit, resteasy, spring-test

Within a Unit/Integration Test, I'm trying to use the RESTEasy embedded server `TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer` or `POJOResourceFactory` inorder to simulate through a `MockHttpRequest.get("/data")` a resource call for test purpose.
My problem is that based on the use of the server or the Resource factory I'm not able to have a non null instance of spring beans which are injected normally within my resources.

Here's some code for clarification, thanks in advance.

**Spring application context :**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cdcfast.service" />
<bean id="simpleResource" class="com.cdcfast.rest.SimpleResource" />
```

**SimpleResource.java :**

```
@Component
@Path("/data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SimpleResource {

@Autowired
private SimpleService service;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Data> getData() {
    return MockDataBase.getInstance().getRows();
}
```

**Unit Test :**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/test/spring/testApplicationContext.xml" })
public class FakeTest {

private Dispatcher dispatcher;

@Before
public void before() {
    dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
    POJOResourceFactory noDefaults = new POJOResourceFactory(SimpleResource.class);
    dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(noDefaults);
}

@Test
public void aTestThatAlwaysPass() throws URISyntaxException {
    MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/data");
    MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();
    dispatcher.invoke(request, response);
    Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    Assertions.assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isNotNull().isNotEmpty();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this before because the RESTEasy factories create the POJO rather than Spring so they don't get wired up which can be worked around in the full container but is less easy in a test. The best way around this is to get a handle to your POJO once the factory creates it and then do something similar to this:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(myPojo);
```

I personally ended up having Spring create the RESTEasy beans using the RESTEasy-Spring plugin and then launching my tests using Jetty, not sure if that is an option for you though.

Answer (score 0):

I exeprienced same problem and i'have solved in similar way as James did:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-context-test.xml" })
public class TestMyService {

    Dispatcher dispatcher;
    private String username = "user";

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    MyService g = new MyService(); //rest service with @autowired spring beans
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(g);
    dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
    dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(g);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestRest() {
    MockHttpRequest request;
    try {
        request = MockHttpRequest.get("/rest/service").header("LOGON_USER", username);
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);
        assertTrue("Error, unexpected status code: " + response.getStatus(), response.getStatus() == 200);
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("********** " + response.getContentAsString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
    }

}
```